# How to export a table in access to CSV with dot in field names through VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, csv

I need to have dot in the field names of the export CSV. I cannot include dot in the access table field, and I cannot find a way to update the CSV field name by VBA. Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: CSV is a plain text format, so you should be able to use VBA to re-write the header line.  Did you try that?

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is quite straightforward. For sample data in [Table1]

```
ID  text column  int column  datetime column      "other" column    
--  -----------  ----------  -------------------  ------------------
 1  foo                   3  1991-11-21 01:23:45  This is a test.   
 2  bar                   9  2013-12-31 23:59:59  ...and so is this.
```

the following VBA code

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub dotCsvExport(TableName As String, FileSpec As String)
    Dim cdb As DAO.Database, tbd As DAO.TableDef, fld As DAO.Field
    Dim s As String, line As String, tempFileSpec As String
    Dim fso As Object  ' FileSystemObject
    Dim fOut As Object  ' TextStream
    Dim fTemp As Object  ' TextStream
    Const TemporaryFolder = 2
    Const ForReading = 1
    Const ForWriting = 2

    Set cdb = CurrentDb
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  ' New FileSystemObject
    tempFileSpec = fso.GetSpecialFolder(TemporaryFolder) & fso.GetTempName

    ' export just the data to a temporary file
    DoCmd.TransferText _
            TransferType:=acExportDelim, _
            TableName:=TableName, _
            FileName:=tempFileSpec, _
            HasFieldNames:=False

    Set fTemp = fso.OpenTextFile(tempFileSpec, ForReading, False)
    Set fOut = fso.OpenTextFile(FileSpec, ForWriting, True)

    ' build the CSV header line, replacing " " with "." in field names
    Set tbd = cdb.TableDefs(TableName)
    line = ""
    For Each fld In tbd.Fields
        s = fld.Name
        s = Replace(s, " ", ".", 1, -1, vbBinaryCompare)
        s = Replace(s, """", """""", 1, -1, vbBinaryCompare)
        If Len(line) > 0 Then
            line = line & ","
        End If
        line = line & """" & s & """"
    Next
    Set fld = Nothing
    Set tbd = Nothing

    ' write the CSV header line to the output file
    fOut.WriteLine line

    ' append the actual data from the temporary file
    fOut.Write fTemp.ReadAll

    fOut.Close
    Set fOut = Nothing
    fTemp.Close
    Set fTemp = Nothing
    Kill tempFileSpec
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set cdb = Nothing
End Sub
```

produces this CSV file

```
"ID","text.column","int.column","datetime.column","""other"".column"
1,"foo",3,1991-11-21 01:23:45,"This is a test."
2,"bar",9,2013-12-31 23:59:59,"...and so is this."
```