# How to Get the Column/Field Name Using Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've copied the recordsource of a subform to a recordset by RecordClone. this subform source is composed by a query (some tables) and all the fields of this query were renamed like, for instance, id_document to "ID Document", date to "Document Date". what I need is to get those new names instead of the original names. instead of id_document, I want to get "ID Document". I tried to get them in the property or fiels collection, unsuccessfully. if any of you know how to do that, please, help me. I'd appreciate your help.

thanks in advance.

P.S.: this is the way I renamed the field in the query design view:
"ID Document": id_document

Comment: Why would you need the new names as opposed to the names in your actual table?

Comment: hi Johnny. I will use those names for creating columns in an Excel spreadsheet. I will also fill this spreadsheet with data from this recordset.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this excellent answer from Gord Thompson (whose name is familiar to many here):

[How to export a table in access to CSV with dot in field names through VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20985549/how-to-export-a-table-in-access-to-csv-with-dot-in-field-names-through-vba)

It's not exactly what you're doing (this person wanted to remove a "." from field names) but you're doing something pretty similar.  You can probably do a DLookup from a crosswalk table to figure out what the column should be named.

Just build a new table called tblCrosswalk and then fill it like this:

```
Old           New
id_document   ID Document
date          Document Date
etc...        etc...
```

Then, in the build the CSV header line section, instead of those "Replace" functions, put this:

```
s = DLookup("New", "tblCrosswalk", "Old = '" & fld.Name & "'")
```

Comment: hi Johnny. thanks for your quick reply. I need to do this by code due to the large amount of screens to be changed and due to the fact of those columns to be renamed once in a while. I think its possible. maybe this information is in the properties or fields or attributes collection but I don't know where exactly it is. what do you think? cheers.

Comment: If you just export the query (with the new field names), shouldn't it export with the new names you've created?